# What are tsetup and thold in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I am learning VHDL. When I tried to make a testbanch I run into these words. What do they mean? I could find any simple explanaition on google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tSetup and tHold aren't VHDL keywords to my knowledge but the minimum setup and hold time for the device being simulated to operate correctly.

- tSetup - The amount of time the data/control needs to be valid before the clock edge.
- tHold - The amount of time the data/control needs to be valid after the clock edge.

A simple graphic explaining this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#Setup.2C_hold.2C_recovery.2C_removal_times

Answer (score 1):

As TOTA says, setup and hold times are digital logic design terms, not VHDL terms.

The vast majority of the time, you do not need to concern yourself with them in testbenches as you are almost always testing internal blocks within your chip and the tools will manage all the timing for you.

When you are working at the device pin level, you can set you models up to check the setup and hold times for violations.  When simulating RTL, there are no delays (usually) modelled, so your timing should be fine.  You can later simulate a back-annotated netlist which has all the real chip delays included and check that you are still going to meet all the timing requirements of your external devices.